# Can the partial sums of independent random variables with no normalization converge in distribution to a constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

If $\{X_n , n\ge 1 \}$ is a sequence of independent random variables and $X_n$ is nondegenerate for at least one $n\ge1$, can there exist a finite constant c such that $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}c$ ?

(Here we are not dividing $S_n$ by any sequence of normalizing constants.)

I am struggling to find an example where this can hold. Could someone please provide an appropriate example, or a proof that no such constant $c$ can exist?

Comment: do you want assume anything else like existing variance or expectation or whatever?

Comment: No I don't want to make any further assumptions about the distribution of the $X_n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Note that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to that constant, so it suffices to prove we cannot have probability to a constant. Note that without loss of generality, we may suppose $c=0$ and that $X_1$ is non-degenerate. Set $Y=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty X_n$, where the limit is taken in probability.

Then the question is (more or less) equivalent to asking if $Y=X$, or if a sequence of random variables can converge in probability to a non-degenerate random variable independent from each of the summands.

Now, convergence in probability implies that a subsequence converges almost surely, so by grouping the $X_i$ we may suppose that the convergence to $Y$ is a.s. Then we have $Y=X$ a.s. for two independent random variables $Y$ and $X$ with $X$ non-constant, which is impossible.

Comment: This *is* an answer.

Comment: I don't quite follow your answer. You said set  $Y=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty X_n$ where the limit is taken in probability. What does that mean? Are we assuming by way of contradiction that $S_n$ converges in probability to 0? Also is $X = X_1$ ?

Comment: @JackBurke The three standard convergence notions in probability are convergence a.s., convergence in probability, and convergence in distribution. This should be explained by any (measure-theoretic) textbook, and it's also on Wikipedia. The answers to your last to questions are both "yes."

Comment: @user4571 Thanks for your response. I'm completely familiar with the notions of convergence. Can you explain why assuming $c=0$ isn't a loss of generality? Also how can I conclude that $X_1\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty X_n$ right off the bat? Where is the $\infty$ coming from when the original $S_n$ only range from 1 to n?

Comment: @JackBurke Sorry, I misunderstood your first question! I think maybe a cleaner way to phrase the argument is to say that limits in probability are unique almost surely, so we have $\lim S_n = c$ almost surely, and then we can subtract $X_1$ from both sides. If $c$ is arbitrary, then subtracting $c$ from $X_1$ allows us to assume that $c=0$.